# What's the meaning of 'cub/s'?

Tags: meaning, word-choice

What's the meaning of "cub" or "cubs" and in what context is it used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Cubs* is the plural of *cub*. *Cub* is the name for the infant offspring of bears, lions and some other creatures.

Comment: Is it a common English word or you had to look it up?

Comment: @donald it is very common.

Comment: It is extremely common. I don't think I ever had to look it up in a dictionary, not even when I was five years old.

Comment: Thanks. One more question, when you say something like: hit cub, snap cub or click cub, is it understandable? or, for example, in the case of click cub, it looks like you're saying "hub". correct?

Comment: @donald: I have never heard *hit cub*, *snap cub* or *click cub* until you wrote them in your comment.

Comment: If you were to say "click cub", you could easily be misheard if you weren't careful to enunciate clearly.  I daresay most native English speakers would say "click on the cub" or "click the cub", though.

Comment: But why "click cub" is so weird? You could say "click shark" meaning the shark of clicks? Is that correct?

Comment: @donald: if you're describing a person inexperienced in clicking, whatever that means in your context, recognizable expression would probably be "cub clicker", similar to the set expressions "cub reporter" and "Cub Scout". Hard to tell much without context.

Comment: Ok! I see your point,thanks. When you have a word (even if it is made up) like clickcub, or clickcrab or, clickcup, how do you read it? From my point, clickcub and clickcup look like "clickhub" and "clickup" whereas in "clickcrab", the "crab" is understandable. I'm wondering how it looks to a native speaker. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

As Robusto points out, the most basic definition of *cub* is *young offspring*, and it is used in reference to those of some common wild animals, such as lions (and other felines), bears, foxes, hyenas, etc. *Cub* can also be compounded with the name of an animal for specificity, e.g. *lion-cub*, *bear-cub*, and so forth.

In some parts of the English-speaking world, the word *cub* is also used in a similar sense for a boy scout in the making; hence, the term *cub scout*. Cubs or cub scouts have to work hard to earn points and gain a certain level of maturity before Akela can declare them boy scouts.

Comment: In addition to that, there are 'cub' is used in urban slang too for [men attracted to older women](http://cub.urbanup.com/3661267) and [certain groups of homosexual men](http://cub.urbanup.com/173269).

Comment: "Cub" was once used to reference any sort of apprentice or new entrant to a profession, "cub reporter" being the most frequent phrase.  It was never that common and I don't think I have heard it for 30 years.